# Write Java Vector To Delimited File

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am connecting to an Oracle database and querying multiple tables. My current code creates the connection and calls a PL/SQL function which contains the query. Once I have the result set, I add it to a Vector (as I am unsure the number of records each query will result in).

My problem is that I am unsure how to write a delimited file from the Vector. I imagine once I have added my result set to it, it is simply one gigantic string. I need to be able to receive each field from the query and delimit between them, as well as keep rows separate.

Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    // instantiate db connection
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SQLException("Oracle JDBC is not available", e);
    }

    // define connection string and parameters
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/sid";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "USERNAME","PASSWORD");


    CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = CALL <functionname>(?)}");

    // get result set and add to a Vector
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    Vector<String> results = new Vector();
    while ( rs.next() ){
        results.add(rs.getString(1));
    }

    // close result set, sql statement, and connection
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();

    // write Vector to output file,
    // where the file name format is MMddyyyy.txt
    try {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
    String dateStr = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    FileWriter fwrite = new FileWriter(dateStr + ".txt");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fwrite);

    for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
    {
        String temp = results.elementAt(i);
        out.write(temp);
    }

    out.close();

}catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
```

I am just unsure how to go about getting the information from the db and writing it to a delimited file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean:  -`out.write(temp + delimiter);`?

Comment: Maybe. I might not have a great understanding of results.elementAt(i). Are the elements in the vector reflective of each field in my result set? Does the vector keep the formatting (e.g. my result set has 10 fields per row, 10 rows. Will the vector look like that?) Maybe it's easier than I thought...

Comment: But you are adding just the first field of each row in your Vector. What you exactly want, please post en example.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear, as I said I have a very elementary understanding of vectors. What I would like is to take a result set that might look like this:

`Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
 Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4
 Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4`

and write it to a file in the same format (excluding headers). I guess I am unsure how the result set is stored in the Vector. My initial thought was that it was one huge string:

`Column1Column2Column3Column4Field1Field2Field3...`

Does this make sense?

Comment: How many columns are there in your table? Is it fixed as 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unsure about the number of fields in each of your `rows`, then probably, it won't be possible. Because to fetch all the field values from database, you need to know what is the type of each fields, and the number of fields.

But, I'll post an example for when you have fixed number of fields, that you know.

Suppose you have `4 columns` per row. Now to display it in tabular form, you would have to use `List of List`.

If you are using `Vector`, use `Vector of List`.

Here's an example for `List of List`: -

```
List<List<String>> results = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

while ( rs.next() ) {
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    tempList.add(rs.getString(1));
    tempList.add(rs.getString(2));
    tempList.add(rs.getString(3));
    tempList.add(rs.getString(4));

    results.add(tempList);
}
```

Then to print it, use this loop: -

```
for (List<String> innerList: results) {
    for (String fields: innerList) {
        System.out.print(fields + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

You can write it in the same form to your `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, the Vector of List will work for me. I see what you were saying now about using the first field of each row. Each query will have a set number of fields because I will be using specific fields, to build a flat file of specific info. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Phoenix.. Exactly. And that's why you can't do it if you don't know the number of fields in each row. Now that you have got it, you can make use of it in your problem. And You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `results.toString()` and truncate the braces(`[]`) from resulting string to write all values as comma separated at once in the file.

```
    //toString() returns comma separated string values enclosed in []
    String resultString = results.toString();

    //truncate leading '[' and termincating ']'
    resultString = resultString.substring(1, resultString.length()-1);

    //if comma is not your delimiter then use String.replaceAll() 
    //to replace `,` with your delimiter

    //write comma separated elements all at once
    out.write(resultString);
```

So here if you have added `str1`, `str2` in the `results` Vector, then `resultString` with have value as  `str1, str2`, which you may write at once using your `BufferedWriter out`.

Also please use `Generics` in both the sides of initialization as:

```
     Vector<String> results = new Vector<String>();
```